# I can't use hooks. I cant setUser with object. What should I do?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with my react hooks not running properly.
I can't update the user's state. The following image depicts the error messages I get when trying to fetch the data and render it:
[image]

It does not seem like my component will render.
Here is my component's source code as requested in the comments:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import map from "../map.png";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

const Profile = (props) => {
  const { id } = props.match.params;
  const [user, setUser] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then((response) => {
        const userAuthor=response.data.filter( (postAuthor) => postAuthor.id !== +id);
        setUser(userAuthor=>userAuthor)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },[]);
  return (
    <div className="content-card">
      {
        console.log(user)
      }
      <Row className="justify-content-center post">
        <Col md="6">
          <h1 className="profile-name">{user.name}</h1>
          <Row>
            <Col md="3" className="profile-key">
              Username
            </Col>
            <Col md="9" className="profile-value">
              {user.username}
            </Col>
            <Col md="3" className="profile-key">
              Email
            </Col>
            <Col md="9" className="profile-value">
              {user.email}
            </Col>
            <Col md="3" className="profile-key">
              Phone
            </Col>
            <Col md="9" className="profile-value">
              {user.phone}
            </Col>
            <Col md="3" className="profile-key">
              Website
            </Col>
            <Col md="9" className="profile-value">
              {user.website}
            </Col>
            <Col md="3" className="profile-key">
              Company
            </Col>
            <Col md="9" className="profile-value">
              {user.company}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
        <Col md="6">
          <img src={map} />
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <h2>{user.name}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Profile;
```

Comment: add minimal-reproducible-code, i think the problems something else

Comment: This is an error that usually occurs when trying to render objects by a mistake. Your state hooks are likely just fine. Are you rendering the user object somewhere?

Comment: You should to use console.log above the `return`. Maybe your error is related to your `{console.log(user)}` as a render object?

Comment: @SimenFjellstad I am filtering api request with  array filter method

Comment: @MustafaÖzgün can you add the rest of the render code from this component in your question?

Comment: @SimenFjellstad https://jsfiddle.net/masL6nbd/ jsfiddle link

Comment: https://prnt.sc/uu1pap I used like this {user.company.name} but I have new errors. Check jsfiddle link please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem which occurs when trying to render objects. Your state hooks are just fine. It seems from the comments that you're trying to render `user.company` which is an object. By changing this to `user.company.name` your code should run just fine

Answer (score -2):

This is an error because you trying to render an objects !

You can't to return a `console.log(user)` as UI components, **just delete it from return** then can you use it after useEffect OR render some data in your UI like *name*

Your state hooks are likely just fine.

Comment: This is false. The console.log in render may be an anti-pattern, but it is not the cause of this issue